# How to UnObfuscate, Obfuscated Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I obfuscated my javascript code using this one http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx but it seems I can' find way to back it to original code.. is there any way?

Comment: most people store copies before obfuscating. Good luck!

Comment: If there is, the original obfuscator isn't very good.

Comment: wrap the code in a named function, run through closure, then run through beautify, then trim off the added wrapper function. pretty readable if you ask me. you can turn of some of the code rewriting to preserve a more logical flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get back some of your code, but almost all function names will be lost and local variables tend to get replaced.

Take for example the default code at [the link you provided](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Default.aspx):

**ORIGINAL**

```
function NewObject(prefix)
{
    var count=0;
    this.SayHello=function(msg)
    {
          count++;
          alert(prefix+msg);
    }
    this.GetCount=function()
    {
          return count;
    }
}
var obj=new NewObject("Message : ");
obj.SayHello("You are welcome.");
```

**OBFUSCATED**

```
var _0x5601=["\x53\x61\x79\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F","\x47\x65\x74\x43\x6F\x75\x6E\x74","\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65\x20\x3A\x20","\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x61\x72\x65\x20\x77\x65\x6C\x63\x6F\x6D\x65\x2E"];function NewObject(_0xa158x2){var _0xa158x3=0;this[_0x5601[0]]=function (_0xa158x4){_0xa158x3++;alert(_0xa158x2+_0xa158x4);} ;this[_0x5601[1]]=function (){return _0xa158x3;} ;} ;var obj= new NewObject(_0x5601[2]);obj.SayHello(_0x5601[3]);
```

**STEP 1 - Decode variable array**

Firstly we need to decode the variable array (the part that starts `var _0x5601=` and ends just before the first `function`). I find the easiest way to do this is to copy and paste the array into Chromes developer console. Just paste the whole line and hit enter, then in the console type the variable name and you'll get something like this:

```
["SayHello", "GetCount", "Message : ", "You are welcome."]
```

**STEP 2 - String Replace code for variable array item**

Next we employ the help of whichever programming language you'd like to parse this new array back into the js. In essence, take your newly decoded array, and perform a string replace the rest of the code. I had PHP handy, so i did this:

```
<?php
// decoded array
$_0x5601 = array("SayHello", "GetCount", "Message : ", "You are welcome.");
// rest of the obfuscated code
$code = "function NewObject(_0xa158x2){var _0xa158x3=0;this[_0x5601[0]]=function (_0xa158x4){_0xa158x3++;alert(_0xa158x2+_0xa158x4);} ;this[_0x5601[1]]=function (){return _0xa158x3;} ;} ;var obj= new NewObject(_0x5601[2]);obj.SayHello(_0x5601[3]);";
// loop over array
for($x = 0; $x < count($_0x5601); $x++){
  // string replace on the code
  $code = str_replace('_0x5601['.$x.']', '"'.$_0x5601[$x].'"', $code);
}
// output result
echo $code;
?>
```

**STEP 3 - BEAUTIFY**

Now, lets "beautify" the code using something like: http://jsbeautifier.org/

```
function NewObject(_0xa158x2) {
    var _0xa158x3 = 0;
    this["SayHello"] = function(_0xa158x4) {
        _0xa158x3++;
        alert(_0xa158x2 + _0xa158x4);
    };
    this["GetCount"] = function() {
        return _0xa158x3;
    };
};
var obj = new NewObject("Message : ");
obj.SayHello("You are welcome.");
```

**STEP 4 - Regex replace array items with object notation**

The last step is to perform one last replace, but this time we need to employ the help of regex. I use an IDE called Sublime Text 2 that has the ability to do find and replace regex (im sure most IDE's have this too).

The regex pattern i used looks like this `\[\"([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)\"\]` to explain:

```
\[\"                    // code must start with ["
(                       // open capturing group
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+        // match all characters a-zA-Z0-9  you may need to adjust this to include -, _ etc as needed
)                       // capture everything in this group
\"\]                    // code must end with "]
```

You want to replace anything that matches this pattern with `.$1`. Resulting in:

```
function NewObject(_0xa158x2) {
    var _0xa158x3 = 0;
    this.SayHello = function(_0xa158x4) {
        _0xa158x3++;
        alert(_0xa158x2 + _0xa158x4);
    };
    this.GetCount = function() {
        return _0xa158x3;
    };
};
var obj = new NewObject("Message : ");
obj.SayHello("You are welcome.");
```

It's not quite as pretty, and as i mentioned local variables have been replaced. But if you know your code it shouldnt be too difficult to understand what they are doing.

Comment: running the last part through closure then re-beautifying yields nicer code, ex: alert(b + c)

Comment: is `alert(b + c)` nicer than `alert(_0xa158x2 + _0xa158x4)` though? they are still nonsensical variable names `:p` each to their own i suppose

Comment: I think it's more readable; _0xa158x2 and _0xa158x4 at a glace look like the same var. it's not better code, but better human factors...

Comment: @dandavis good point, personally tiny vars get lost in the sea of letters for me, and i end up training my eyes to look for the `_0xa158` prefix and only reading the post `x` suffix.. but like i said each to their own `:)`